# JBoss 7 - Could not parse file META-INF/hornetq-jms.xml

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, hornetq, jms-topic

I need to configure JMS topic when my web app deploying. I had to use deployment descriptor for this. 
hornetq-jms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schemas/hornetq-jms.xsd ">

<connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
    <connectors>
       <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
        <entry name="InVmConnectionFactory"/>
    </entries>
</connection-factory>

<queue name="OrderQueue">
    <entry name="queues/beanQueue"/>
</queue>

</configuration>
```

But during deployment i`ve got errors like this:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:hornetq}configuration'
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you can have a hornetq-jms on the meta-inf with jboss 7. you're supposed to use the standalone-full.xml for those things now.

Comment: @Clebert I can`t change parameters in servers config. I need to create topic while deploying the app or maybe in the app but I can`t find how to do it from the running app too. It`s so easy in the glassfish and such a pain in jBoss 7 :(

Comment: You should probably ask on the JBoss user's forum. They are better on answering this. Once you do that you can feed the question here.

Comment: BTW: I think there's a solution for that.. it's just different on AS7 and I'm not sure now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was answered [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/222475) I had used an old syntax of hornetq-jms.xml.
This is example of correct hornetq-jms.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source Copyright 2012, Red Hat, Inc.
and/or its affiliates, and individual contributors by the @authors tag. See
the copyright.txt in the distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required
by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<messaging-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:messaging-deployment:1.0">
    <hornetq-server>
        <jms-destinations>
            <jms-queue name="HELLOWORLDMDBQueue">
                <entry name="/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue"/>
            </jms-queue>
            <jms-topic name="HELLOWORLDMDBTopic">
                <entry name="/topic/HELLOWORLDMDBTopic"/>
            </jms-topic>
        </jms-destinations>
    </hornetq-server>
</messaging-deployment>
```